# How to sum Total Time for each user in a while loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, sum

I have this table (for example)

```
    id      userId     totalHours      isOt
    1       1          0830            1
    2       4          0630            0
    3       1          0730            0
    4       2          0900            1
```

I need to find the totalHours for each user but they should be shown once for each user (Group By)

And then, if the totalHours was awarded as OT (over time == 1) the difference between totalHours minus 0800 hours should be summed up too and shown in another column.

I have tried to join this table with user table but the loop seems so wrong which ended up totalling all last values in every loop to another.

Hope there will be anyone who can help and your help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show the code of what you tried, so that people can help you find what was not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Do it in your database query, not PHP:

```
SELECT UserId,
       SUM(totalHours) AS totalTime,
       SUM(IF(isOt, totalhours-800, 0)) AS totalOt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY UserId
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, how can i post a table inside this question, i have no knowledge of posting with code here.

Comment: Paste pre-formatted text, then use the `{}` code markup tool.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I have make the fix.
And after trying your suggested query, some row whose have totalHours less than 0800 returns negative value (substraction happened)

Comment: If you don't want to allow negatives, use `GREATEST(0, totalHours-800)`.

Comment: BTW, are these times normal numbers that can be added and subtracted, or are they `HHMM`? You need to convert them to ordinary numbers to use regular arithmetic on them.

Comment: To convert HHMM to total minutes, use `60*FLOOR(totaltime/100) + totaltime%100`

Comment: SELECT UserId,
       SUM(totalHours) AS totalTime,
       SUM(IF GREATEST(0, totalHours-800)) AS totalOt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY UserId

is it like this?

Comment: `SUM(IF(isOt, GREATEST(0, totalHours-800), 0) AS totalOt`

Comment: it will be OT after granted by superior :)
if not, that totalHours is not to be counted as OT